# roscd: No such package/stack 'beginner_tutorials'

Tags: ros, roscd, beginner-tutorials, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have found a bunch of questions about the same issue, but I don't think my problem is the same.

So basically, I am super new to ROS and was going through tutorial page ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

I created a package using:
~/catkin_ws/src$ catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp

It gave me next lines:

Created file beginner_tutorials/package.xml
Created file beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt
Created folder beginner_tutorials/include
Created folder beginner_tutorials/src
Successfully created files in /home/natalia/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials. Please adjust the values in package.xml.

Then I try command like
roscd beginner_tutorials
and it says:
roscd: No such package/stack 'beginner_tutorials'

I have checked my path with
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
and got:
/home/natalia/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks

and beginner_tutorials folder is in src, so it seems that path is already correct.

Do you have any suggestions what might be wrong?

---

So after trying rospack profile --length=200 I got:

0.005637   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks

0.001263   /home/natalia/catkin_ws/src

0.001116   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/navigation

0.000486   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo

0.000481   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/navigation_tutorials

0.000405   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/visualization_tutorials

0.000317   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/common_tutorials

0.000285   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/executive_smach

0.000198   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/physics_ode

0.000185   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/geometry_tutorials

0.000167   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/robot_model_tutorials

0.000109   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/slam_gmapping

0.000107   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/robot_model_visualization

0.000092   /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/documentation

0.000036 * /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/laser_pipeline

0.000034 * /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/common

So I think that there is nothing wrong with path? But I still cannot use roscd or rospack etc. to packages I create. However, it works fine for roscpp, for example.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65003/roscd:-no-such-package/stack-%27beginner_tutorials%27/) by [Natti](https://answers.ros.org/users/5133/natti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2013-06-12

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe it's just a missing `catkin_make` and `source devel/setup.bash`, although given the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH it should work.

You could try something like `rospack profile --length=200` to see what it searches.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 21

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Natti](https://answers.ros.org/users/5133/natti/) on 2013-06-13**:
Ah, tried  catkin_make and source devel/setup.bash and now it works!! Thank you ^__^

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-13**:
@Natti please accept this answer using the checkmark at the left.

**Comment by [Andres](https://answers.ros.org/users/5608/andres/) on 2013-07-27**:
I had the same problem. For step by step beginners:
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/
$ catkin_make
this will traverse the packages and add a subdirectory.
followed by
$ source devel/setup.bash

**Comment by [Allison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21801/allison/) on 2015-03-06**:
You can also create an alias to run all of the commands:

```
alias cat_make='cd ~/catkin_ws/ && catkin_make && source devel/setup.bash'
```

so all the commands will be run by just typing cat_make (or another alias name you choose)

**Comment by [Tiago_Dev_Br](https://answers.ros.org/users/108702/tiago_dev_br/) on 2022-06-29**:
Thanks a lot. When i set catkin_make and source devel/setup.bash worked.